# How To Translate contact us Meta description in magento2?

Tags: magento2, contact-us, translate, title, meta-description

vendor/magento/module-contact/view/frontend/layout/contact_index_index.xml

```
<head>
     <title>Contact Us</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Have inquiries? Contact us now." />
   </head>
```

How To Translate contact us **Meta description**?

I already put **translation .csv** file. but still nowt working.  
Please someone help me.

Comment: did you try this: `content=__('Have inquiries? Contact us now.')`?

Comment: yes. just tried now. can't like that.

Comment: no not resolved this issue in magento 2.4.6

Answer (score 0):

I Faced the Similar issue. In that case I override the this xml file `[vendor/magento/module-contact/view/frontend/layout/contact_index_index.xml]

Create a file in below path

app/design/frontend/{namespace}/{themename}/Magento_Contact/layout/contact_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
       <title>Contact Us</title>
    <meta name="description" content="<transalated value of 'Have inquiries? Contact us now.'>" />
    </head>
</page>
```

I Hope this answer help for you.

Comment: can't. When override xml file, it show default contact form and not include <meta name="description"> @Singhe